# Update a record in ASP .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

Today in the interview I faced a question tat I had no clue about. Being a  newbie into ASP .Net MVC I had no other way but to ask the experts about it.

"In your MVC Application ,data are being stored into a RDBMS System. In a .cshtml page ,there is a button to update the existing records into DB.

**Now suppose two users from different parts of the Globe are at the same time are trying to update a common record. But by the the time the second user hits the submit button, you already submitted the update. In that case the second user , when would be pressing the submit won't be able to submit. Instead the page would reloaded for the second user with the updated info, discarding the changes.And then only he would be able to go on with the update**"

How could you achieve that in ASP .Net MVC?

I though thought it might be something from the DB Side coding also , but I have no clue how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a strategy for managing [concurrency](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). How you do this depends largely on the business rules of the application and the type of conflict that arises when two or more people attempt to change the same record.

Most often, you will add a column called `RowVersion` which will be a `timestamp` type. Whenever you display records to be updated, you also select the current `RowVersion` value and usually store it in a hidden field. The update operation will include the `RowVersion` field, which gets a new value, but before you commit an update operation, you compare the `RowVersion` value you have with the current one in the database. If they are different, someone else has updated the row during the time that it took you to get the record to be updated and then tried to change it. You determine how to proceed based on the application's business rules.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous Tasks do the database operations , so even if another user tries to update , the first process runs in the background asynchronously

Comment: What does asynchronous data access have to do with managing concurrency?

Comment: I was relating to asynchronous when more than one user tries to access the database for any operation, not necessarily for that specific field

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question which is about concurrency. You have to decide on and implement a concurrency management strategy regardless whether you are using async data access.

Comment: Yes i do agree concurrency management strategy has to be implemented ,but it has to be done asynchronously

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be done asynchronously. The two issues are not related at all. People have been managing concurrency way before async was added to .NET.

Comment: Yes but now its done asynchronously so that a second user need not wait for the first users operation to be complete.

Comment: But this has nothing at all to do with concurrency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106205/discussion-between-dare-g-and-mike-brind).